# Cannot delete file on cifs share

Tags: linux

I downloaded a file on a cifs share under Linux Mint with the user "gab". I had to format this computer and I reinstalled Mint. I cannot delete the files that were downloaded with the first Mint. Here's what I've tried.

```
sudo chmod 777 folder //permission denied
sudo chown gab folder //permission denied
```

Tried both with root access aswell, same result. On Windows, if I try to delete the folder it gives the error: You require permission from Unix user\1000 to modify this file. If I try changing the owner/permissions on windows, I get an access denied error. Here's a ls -la of the folder:

```
 ls -la '/media/yoshi_share/Torrents/delete_me' total 1015132
drwxrwxr-x  2 gab gab          0 May 21 03:12 .
drwxrwxrwx 15 gab 702          0 May 30 00:19 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 gab gab         92 Dec 13 00:20 some_file.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 gab gab 1038470195 Dec 13 00:20 some_file.mkv
```

I've mounted the share using uid=gab and uid=1000 because it was originally created this way. Still no luck with chmod or chown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to delete the file. I'm new to linux and I found out I had monted the share on the first OS using NFS. I remounted with nfs and was able to delete the files.